# How to get row count for a items with value x in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following object

```
    var countries = [
        {country: "Ireland", continent: "Europe", language: "English"},
        {country: "Spain", continent: "Europe", language: "Spanish"},
        {country: "United Kingdom", continent: "Europe", language: "English"},
        {country: "France", continent: "Europe", language: "French"},
        {country: "Germany", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
        {country: "Sweden", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
        {country: "Norway", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
        {country: "Italy", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
        {country: "Greece", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
        {country: "Iceland", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
        {country: "Portugal", continent: "Europe", language: "Portuguese"},
        {country: "Malta", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
        {country: "Brazil", continent: "South America", language: "Portuguese"},
        {country: "Argentina", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
        {country: "Colombia", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
        {country: "Peru", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
        {country: "Venezuela", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
        {country: "Uruguay", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"}
    ];
```

How can I count the objects with for example `continent` === 'South America' ? It is a JSON list of obejcts returned from a WebService within an AngularJS Controller.

Comment: So result should be 0 or 6?

Comment: Sorry my fault! I have corrected the question. I want to search for 'South America' and the result should be 6.

Comment: `countries.filter(country => country.continent == 'America').length`

Comment: @Jose: Is this pure Javascript? And fast if i even would have 1.000 items?

Comment: Yes! it's pure javascript. With filter function you just simply loop the array and get a new array filtered by the condition, in this case `country.continent == 'South America' `, and get the length of this array. fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g8tat8fc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var countries = [{"country":"Ireland","continent":"Europe","language":"English"},{"country":"Spain","continent":"Europe","language":"Spanish"},{"country":"United Kingdom","continent":"Europe","language":"English"},{"country":"France","continent":"Europe","language":"French"},{"country":"Germany","continent":"Europe","language":"(other)"},{"country":"Sweden","continent":"Europe","language":"(other)"},{"country":"Norway","continent":"Europe","language":"(other)"},{"country":"Italy","continent":"Europe","language":"(other)"},{"country":"Greece","continent":"Europe","language":"(other)"},{"country":"Iceland","continent":"Europe","language":"(other)"},{"country":"Portugal","continent":"Europe","language":"Portuguese"},{"country":"Malta","continent":"Europe","language":"(other)"},{"country":"Brazil","continent":"South America","language":"Portuguese"},{"country":"Argentina","continent":"South America","language":"Spanish"},{"country":"Colombia","continent":"South America","language":"Spanish"},{"country":"Peru","continent":"South America","language":"Spanish"},{"country":"Venezuela","continent":"South America","language":"Spanish"},{"country":"Uruguay","continent":"South America","language":"Spanish"}]
    
var result = countries.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(e.continent === 'South America') r++
  return r;
}, 0);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array, like :

`var southAfrikaResult = []`

Then you loop on your **countries** array (with angular.forEach) and check if

```
item.continent === 'South Afika'
```

If so, then push item into your southAfricaResult. Your final result will be :

```
var your_result = southAfricaResult.length;
```

Edit : the filter solution proposed by Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo it way better.

Answer (score 0):

I would do sth like

```
var countries = [
    {country: "Ireland", continent: "Europe", language: "English"},
    {country: "Spain", continent: "Europe", language: "Spanish"},
    {country: "United Kingdom", continent: "Europe", language: "English"},
    {country: "France", continent: "Europe", language: "French"},
    {country: "Germany", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
    {country: "Sweden", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
    {country: "Norway", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
    {country: "Italy", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
    {country: "Greece", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
    {country: "Iceland", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
    {country: "Portugal", continent: "Europe", language: "Portuguese"},
    {country: "Malta", continent: "Europe", language: "(other)"},
    {country: "Brazil", continent: "South America", language: "Portuguese"},
    {country: "Argentina", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
    {country: "Colombia", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
    {country: "Peru", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
    {country: "Venezuela", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"},
    {country: "Uruguay", continent: "South America", language: "Spanish"}
];

j = 0;
newCountry = [];    

for(i=0; i<countries.length; i++)
{
    if(countries[i]['continent'] == 'South America')
    { 
        j++; //only for size
        newCountry.push(countries[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks that you have only number of countries but in newCountry you will have array with countries in that continent and then you can use newCountry.length and you will get same result.

Answer (score 0):

you can create array like this

```
var result = [];
```

You angular.foreach loop

```
angular.forEach(countries, function(value, key) {
if(value.continent == "South America")
       //your logic
  result.push(value.continent);
});
```

finally you count the array length

```
var count = result.length;
```

If you want to get to more detail in any step, Click [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUjZ_3hvbOAhVHuY8KHZ4wBgAQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fangularjs-angularforeach-getting-key-and-value&usg=AFQjCNFnQahF8T1Kcp9heWPApdSvtSrgVg&sig2=ZwQYnqQfavE80hHpu_9Hzg)!